# Reverse Sort for a Templated Heap class

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, heap, reverse

I have created a Templated Heap Class and have managed to sort the list in ascending order through the use of a custom iterator class, i was just wondering how i would sort it in reverse order.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Heap<T>::sort_heap(DynamicArrayIter<T> first, DynamicArrayIter<T> second) {
    int size = 0;
    for (DynamicArrayIter<T> iter = first; iter != second; ++iter) {
        size++;
    }
    T temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            if (contents.at(j) < contents.at(i)) {
                temp = contents.at(i);
                contents.at(i) = contents.at(j);
                contents.at(j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,Soz could not get code insert to work...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed It, Just changed the

```
if (contents.at(j) < contents.at(i))
```

to

```
if (contents.at(j) > contents.at(i))
```